# Xpages valuePicker add value

Tags: view, xpages

Is there a way to add a field into the valuePicker with the possibility of adding new values in it? The valuePicker get's the values from a view, and I wouldn't want to add another addButton to add some values withing that view, in separate way. I would like a dialogBox like the valuePicker + the option to add new documents withing it. It is possible?

Answer (score 2):

That functionality isn't available in the Value Picker. It's unlikely to be added, because of the variety of dataProviders, which makes it difficult to know where to add the option to make it available to other documents, and also ensure validation of options.

Typeahead on an Edit Box control allows you to add entries not in the list.

Alternatively, you can add a separate Edit Box to your XPage to include a value not in the list. But if you want to store the new option in the same field, you'll need to write the code to add the option to the source of the list. E.g. if it's the dataProvider of your Value Picker is a dominoViewValuePicker, you'll need to create a document in that view as well; if it's a simpleValuePicker, you'll need to compute the options so they also look to this field. Otherwise, when the user edits the document again, the option will not be available in the list, so may get removed.

Comment: I have a set of options, but I want to add the possibility to the user to add more options and those to be saved also.

Comment: My approach would be to give an Edit Box to add options not in the list. I'd add an eventHandler onto that to add the value store the new value in a field in the document as well as add it to the field of options selected. The Value Picker would use the static list as well as the field - the property can be computed to combine the two.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want the user to insert new values into a field in valuePicker? Instead, let the user add the new value direct into the field which is the valuePicker related to.

Comment: After saving document the new value should be listed in view and therefore be part of valuePicker's value list next time.